# SQLcl Oracle to export data to CSV without blank first line and without carriage return character at the end

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqlcl

For reasons, I am using the following here-doc approach to export data to CSV.

```
$ /oracle/sqlcl/bin/sql -s username/password@//host.mybiz.com.my:1521/dwh > arca.csv <<EOF
SET SQLFORMAT CSV
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TERMOUT OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET NEWPAGE NONE
SELECT
    *
FROM ORDER.SALES
WHERE ROWNUM < 100;
EOF
```

This however produces a CSV file with empty first line and with unquoted carriage return at the end, as complained by `psql` tool when I want to load to Postgres

Below error happens because the CSV file has blank row as first line. The column names are read as data instead, causing type error.

```
$ psql -c "\COPY raw_data.arca FROM arca.csv CSV HEADER"
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "FILE_DATE"
CONTEXT:  COPY arca, line 2, column file_date: "FILE_DATE"
```

If I remove the blank row manually, the following error then occurs because of carriage return character at the end of data

```
$ psql -c "\COPY raw_data.arca FROM arca.csv CSV HEADER"
ERROR:  unquoted carriage return found in data
HINT:  Use quoted CSV field to represent carriage return.
CONTEXT:  COPY arca, line 101
```

How do I correctly use sqlcl with here-doc approach to produce CSV file without first blank line, and carriage return ending?

Comment: Actually, the code you show will _not_ produce what you say it will.  It will produce a syntax error.  Your "AND ROWNUM < 100"  (the "AND" predicate) is a extension of the WHERE clause.  But the code you show has no WHERE clause.

Comment: ya .. actually this is from production setup that i cannot copy and paste directly into StackExchange. Had to edit here without retesting.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the UNLOAD TABLE command ?

```
sql -s scott/tiger@localhost:1521/spatialdb <<EOF
unload table us_cities
EOF
```

Or even this simple one-liner:

```
echo "unload table us_cities" | sql -s scott/tiger@localhost:1521/spatialdb
```

This creates file `US_CITIES_DATA_TABLE.csv` in your current directory.

Check the help about the UNLOAD command to get details about various options for formatting the output.

Comment: I have to check it out, never use UNLOAD. does it work if it's a SELECT query rather than a table?

Comment: No. But you can unload from a view.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Should have checked beforehand: NO, UNLOAD does NOT support views, only tables.